# OSRM Server setup using docker-compose - container exited

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, microservices, osrm

I'm trying to setup the OSRM server on the top of Docker. I need to configure it using docker-compose.yml inside my micro-services project using .net core.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  test_web:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}osrmweb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: OSRM_WEB/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 1111

  osrm-data:
    image: irony/osrm5
    volumes:
      - /data

  osrm:
    image: irony/osrm5 
    volumes: 
      - osrm-data
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    command: ./start.sh Sweden http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/sweden-latest.osm.pbf
```

I have this docker-compose.yml file. When I run the `docker-compose up` there is no error but the container is Exited. [![ ][1]][1]

I can't see any response in this url.

```
https://localhost:5000/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407;13.428555,52.523219?overview=false
```

Is there anything else I need to do in configurations? Any suggestions?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9BLz.png

Answer (score 0):

Try an HTTP URL instead of HTTPS:

> http://localhost:5000/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.397634,52.529407;13.428555,52.523219?overview=false

Also, the red "Exited" statuses in your screenshot are ok, because there are some one-time commands to be executed, when setting up an [OSRM backend](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend) service:

- Download the sweden-latest.osm.pbf file (and exit)
- osrm-extract (and exit)
- osrm-partition (and exit)
- osrm-customize (and exit)

Finally the osrm-routed is run (and does not exit) and listens at the port 5000